# ThreeJS multicolor material

Tags: material, color-management, three.js, masking

### How can I have a multicolor material in ThreeJS?

I'm looking for a way to have **a single material and use one or more b/w masks to color the surface of the model with the same amount of colors**; the masks will not blend/overlap each others, so no color blending, just some areas of one color and other of another.

I'm sure it is actually possible with ThreeJS to achieve this, but I couldn't find any example on how to do this.

Having played with Blender I'm used to assign multiple materials to specific mesh faces for easiest models and using multiple shaders (or even entire materials) with textures masks, but in a web context I assume the best practice is to have a single model/mesh to which assign a single material.

Just to be clear, the final use case will be a 3d model created with external tool (blender, maya, etc) with all necessary textures to recreate a single material, this way I can asynchronously download each assets for page speed.

The problem is how then to recreate the final material with all the assets.